# Measure bandwidth by client IP in realtime

Tags: bandwidth, denial-of-service

I have been recently attacked using DoS attack on random ports.

I wasn't able to get the attackers IP and now I would like to find it.

What tool can show me bandwidth (in Kbits/Mbits) used by each client IP?

It's dedicated server. I know that I'm under attack because of flow charts in dedi's panel (up to 800 mbps)
Thanks for all your replies.

Comment: Are you directly connected to the Internet? Are you behind a router? We need a lot more information here.

Comment: Hmmm... You don't have any information on the "attacker" yet you know you were "attacked". How so?

Comment: In addition, how is knowing the client bandwidth going to help you find the culprit? Do legitimate clients not use any bandwidth?

Comment: edited the question, added info.

Answer (score 0):

You want flow monitoring. See

- http://sectools.org/traffic-monitors.html
- http://www.slac.stanford.edu/xorg/nmtf/nmtf-tools.html#flow-com
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_traffic_measurement#Some_available_tools

Answer (score 0):

Cacti is a pretty good software package for this sort of thing, as is nagios. But as this DoS attack has already occurred, they won't be of much use - they need to be running at the time.

Comment: Of course I know. I think it will happen again.

Answer (score 0):

[iftop](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/iftop/) will show you that information live, though not historically.